# reliable/redundant PSU for SOHO server build

Tags: power-supply, nas, redundancy

I am after reliable SOHO server build. I went with ECC RAM, quality NAS-grade harddrive and now I am looking at the PSU.

I cannot seem to find any good redundant PSUs that would fit into the ATX form-factor. Are there any good choices?

Alternatively, what would be a good strategy on replacing a PSU - at which time? What would be the tell-tale signs of it going off? With HDDs in redundant arrays, ECC memory and properly burnt-in motherboard + CPU, it seems to be me that normal PSU is the weak link here. I've found a few discussions here but nothing that would address this specific question:

Is it worth modding/getting redundant PSU or is there an existing, accepted strategy on how often to replace PSU in a single-configuration setup?

I've also seen [manufacturers](http://www.ixsystems.com/storage/freenas/) go with a single-PSU configurations on their smaller machines but I am still not convinced that it's something I want to do in a production environment.

**Sources:**

https://serverfault.com/questions/210337/importance-of-redundant-power-supply

http://www.overclock.net/t/1373866/redundant-atx-power-supply

http://athenapower.com/node/242